# how to do screen+audio recording when mac is muted?

Tags: mac, audio, screen-capture, quicktime

I want to record a video+audio on hangout (not sure if on the web or on an app) while i'm in another meeting.

I saw this tutorial using quicktime:
http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/4587/use-quicktime-player-to-capture-web-video-and-audio/

However it won't record audio when my Mac is muted.

How can record audio as well without actually hearing it when played on my Mac?

Comment: Turn your speakers off?

Comment: I have only built in speaker. Muting them results in capture without audio. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I used quicktime + soundflower.

Worked well :)

Comment: Hi Elad, it's great that you solved it - would you be able to mark your answer as the solution, and also expand upon your answer  (and maybe even show some screenshots if it is helpful) to show what you did with Soundflower to get it working? It might be obvious to you and me but somebody else might have the same issue in the future and a detailed answer might stop them from asking a duplicate question unnecessarily.